# My external display is bad with mac book retina display

Tags: macbook, external-display, macbook-pro-retina

I have mac book pro retina display 15".

I have [BENQ monitor GW2450](http://www.benq.com/product/monitor/gw2450/)

My the display is not clear and font looks very bad like some white dots in all fonts. Loks like resolution is not right.

In the Mac display the resolution is set at `1080p`

DO need to replace the monitor or i can fix it to looks clear

Comment: sure it's not just the resolution difference - 15" retina 2560x1600, 24" BenQ 1920x1080... is gonna look pretty fuzzy next to the retina. Post pictures so we could have a better guess.

Comment: @Tetsujin i think you may be right. This is the screen shot. http://s30.postimg.org/z9cx5eey9/Screen_Shot_2014_11_18_at_8_03_48_am.png . If i see that screenshot in on retina then it looks ok but if i see in monitor then it looks same.

Comment: I'm 85% certain that's just the resolution difference